# Android studio: Read data from Google spreadsheet using retrofit2 (GET)

Tags: java, android, google-sheets, retrofit

Right now I'm able to post data using a method from "Blundell
Android Developer Tutorials and Blog", but I need to read data from different entries.

This is the interface for post:

```
public interface WebServiceSpreadsheet {

    @POST("1FAIpQLSfKGadkannwHzBhQDhJ9VBidB9oUhX-0mxI6vnyNCzo5G_YSg/formResponse")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<Void> SpreadshettData(
        @Field("entry.1286709617") String ActuatorsApp
    );

}
```

And the Java code to post:

```
public class ActActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_act);
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(
            "https://docs.google.com/a/acorntechmx.com/forms/d/e/")
            .build();

        final WebServiceSpreadsheet spreadsheetWebService = 
            retrofit.create(WebServiceSpreadsheet.class);


        findViewById(R.id.btnFan1).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String FanON1 = "Fan ON Hour";

                    Call<Void> SpreadsheetData = 
                        spreadsheetWebService.SpreadshettData(FanON1);
                    SpreadsheetData.enqueue(callCallback);
                }
            }
    );
```

What should I do to read data with the `GET` method from `retrofit2`?

Answer (score 0):

To read data from the Google Sheets API with the `GET` method from `retrofit2` you should add some methods to your `WebServiceSpreadsheet` interface:

Returns the spreadsheet at the given ID:

```
  @GET("/v4/spreadsheets/1FAIpQLSfKGadkannwHzBhQDhJ9VBidB9oUhX-0mxI6vnyNCzo5G_YSg")
  Call<Spreadsheet> get(@Path("spreadsheetId") String spreadsheetId);
```

After that you may call the method like:

```
Call<Spreadsheet> spreadsheet = spreadsheetWebService.get(“1FAIpQLSfKGadkannwHzBhQDhJ9VBidB9oUhX-0mxI6vnyNCzo5G_YSg”);
```

You may use [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/) as a reference

To use Google Sheets API in your Android app this is a shortlist to check:

1. [Enable Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/) for your project or create new project and enable API for it.
2. [Generate Release/Debug keystores](https://gist.github.com/henriquemenezes/70feb8fff20a19a65346e48786bedb8f) for your project and get SHA1 key fingerprint.
3. Obtain API_KEY from [Google Cloud Platform console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) by inserting the package name and SHA1 key fingerprint from previous step to your project.
4. Add these to your `build.gradle` (Module app):

   implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev525-1.23.0') 
       {
         exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
       }

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interface that should work for read-only publicly visible sheets:

```
public interface SheetsApi {

  @GET("/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}?majorDimension=ROWS")
  Call<SheetsValuesResponse> getValues(
      @Path("spreadsheetId") String sheetId,
      @Path("range") String range,
      @Query("key") String apiKey);

  @GET("/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}")
  Call<GetSheetResponse> getSheets(
      @Path("spreadsheetId") String sheetId, @Query("key") String apiKey);
}
```